# 220V AC/DC converter on 110V circuit

Tags: battery-charging, ac-dc

I have an AC/DC converter:

> input AC 220-240V 50/60Hz

> output DC 3.6-10.8V 1.5A.

It is a charger for an electric drill battery (Li-ion 10.8V 4Ah).

What would happen if I were to plug this converter on a 110V circuit? Would the DC voltage be half what it is supposed to be?
Would the battery charge at all, albeit slower?

Comment: Impossible to say without analyzing the circuitry.

Comment: Depends on the circuit. As it's a battery charger not just an unregulated supply it's most likely to not work at all.